# Where can I find videos of someone (who knows what they're doing) writing PHP?

Tags: php, video

Its been YEARS since I did any PHP.

I am working in .NET but supposed to be teaming up with some PHP people. I'd really like to get up to speed a little in whats changed in the language and the IDE tools - but I really don't have the time nor energy to learn anything. I probably won't have to write any PHP, but I want to.

I'm looking therefore for some kind of videos [like these .NET ones](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-422.aspx) where you get to see the IDE, the basic way of working etc. etc. I'm not looking for someone using notepad - I want something where I can see how real expert PHP programmers work.

Comment: In all friendliness. If you don't have any time or energy to study PHP, then I suggest you take the opportunity to not write any PHP. A video of someone working won't get you up to speed, it will only show you a fraction of things.

Comment: @kent friendliness appreciated. this is more about me getting to know what PHP is really like these days compared to .NET - especially if i'm trying to convince people why our main site should be .NET. i'm really just looking for a peek into the PHP world of today - but one i can get with min effort

Comment: It sounds like you want a video of someone writing bad or ugly PHP code so you can make your point. Perhaps you could make a screencast of yourself writing PHP as you remember it. Should be effective. Please forgive me if I've completely missed the mark.

Comment: @gloryfish that made me laugh ;-) your comment does get closer to the mark of one of my goals - but at the same time i genuinely do want to see what the tools are like - not in depth, just a fly one wall. wish id made a video of myself using vi to write java, running it across network on a Mac in 98

Comment: @Simon That sounds...non optimal? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the thing is that with PHP there is no single "the IDE" and "the way". there is a multitude of tools, frameworks, libraries, extensions, IDEs, plugins, etc.

my favourite IDE for PHP is **Aptana** and the nice thing about Aptana is that there is Aptana.tv: **http://www.aptana.tv/** which has very nice video-casts about all aspects of the IDE...

the Video **PHPEditorPart1** is quite close to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

I find [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com) a pretty useful resource, even though the videos aren't free. If you can get your company to spring for the cost of a login it tends to be a pretty decent place for anyone in the office to learn a few new skills.

For free stuff I find the [learn list](http://www.thelearnlist.com/php.php) pretty decent and the PHP link in the learn list got me [this site](http://www.phpvideotutorials.com/) for php videos.

Hopefully something useful for you in those links.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I can suggest is the CodeIgniter how-to videos [here](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/). It should give you a general idea how the architecture of a typical PHP app is layed out and how a coder goes about creating it.

Whatever you do, do NOT search for PHP on Youtube.

Comment: ironically i didnt even think to do that

Answer (score -1):

PHP has no specific IDE. You can write it in notepad or vi if you felt like it.

Your best bet is to start reading books.  Videos are great but learning the methodology is way more important than learning any IDE.  When you watch videos you are missing out on so many side details its crazy.

Comment: that's not correct, there are a few very good IDEs for PHP like Aptana PHP, Zend Studio, Eclipse PHP, ...

Comment: @tharkun, where did he say that there was no php ide?

Comment: correct, no specific IDE.  Many languages ship with the IDE and compiler bundled, PHP is IDE agnostic. :)